# Why can primary key column be empty in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints, primary-key

I have a table with only 1 primary column (nvarchar), as in the designer, it's marked as primary key and not allow nulls. But by somehow, there is a row in that table with the key value being empty, it's of course not null and doesn't duplicate with any other rows in the primary key column and there isn't any conflict or violation occurring.

However as far as I know, that kind of value (empty) is not allowed for a primary column in SQL Server. I wonder if there is any option to turn on to make it work properly. Or I have to check the value myself through CHECK constraint or right in C# code (before updating).

Your help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Empty-string" is a string with length of zero. It is NOT NULL, so it doesn't violate a null check. It most certainly IS an allowed value for a character-based primary key column in SQL Server. If the empty string value is not allowed by the business, a check constraint would be the best way to implement this as a business rule. That way, clients which might not know about the rule can't violate it.

This code runs without violations in SQL Server, I just tested it just to be sure.

```
create table TestTable (
  myKey varchar(10) primary key,
  myData int
)
GO

insert TestTable
select '', 1
```

Comment: Well, testing using code is not what I did, I tested using Designer and it showed an error dialog. If so, it's not different from SQL Server. However what about the option or setting? (before considering Check constraint or other data validations). Thanks!

Comment: There is an option that causes NULL to be treated as empty string in string concatenation operations, but nothing similar for tables. Probably, the table editor you're using is converting empty to null before submitting the update - that's tool behavior so I'm not sure how to fix that. You could script your update from the tool and see what the SQL really is. Keep in mind all those tools work by sending plain old SQL to the server. If you can intercept that somehow (like with the profiler) then you could see what it's doing.

Comment: Oh BTW - using the designers will really hurt you when learning SQL - you need to learn to hand-code SQL. At that point, the designers become more-or-less useless because you can code faster than you can mouse around.